# word vsto: Create empty Table no cols, no rows

Tags: c#, vsto

Is it possible to create an empty table

since `doc.Tables.Add(foo,rows,cols)` has
the condition col > 0; rows > 0.

I add rows and cols customized and if is use
`doc.Tables.Add(foo,1,1)`

I always have an empty
Header and an empty left column.

Comment: What's the utility of an empty table?

Comment: Nothing, therefore I add rows and cols.

Comment: Then I would just structure your logic to add rows and columns based on the dimensions you need.

Comment: My structure is not rectengular but jagged.